# How to get map data without rendering it (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of adresses in my database that i can put into array in JS, but from now I want to display distance between me and them, like

me: Warsaw
array[0]: Berlin
array[1]: Moscov
array[2]: Amsterdam
array[3]: London

(array elements contains precise adresses, examples above are just like pseudocode)

I already made a script that can get distance between 2 points on map, but I am rendering map to do this, and this takes some time so it is not acceptable way if I want to display 20 distance entries at once

It don't have to be distance data as this can be overhelming question, but I just want to know how to fetch **any** data without waiting the time of map rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the map at all for this?  There are other approaches you can use.

See here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I've used the "[haversine](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#JavaScript)" method myself:

```
function haversine() {
       var radians = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(deg) { return deg/180.0 * Math.PI; });
       var lat1 = radians[0], lon1 = radians[1], lat2 = radians[2], lon2 = radians[3];
       var R = 6372.8; // km
       var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
       var dLon = lon2 - lon1;
       var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat /2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon /2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
       var c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
       return R * c;
}
console.log(haversine(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40));
```